# problem deploying RailsTutorial Chap 11 on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm following the Rails Tutorial and just finished Chap 11.  No errors on localhost, but a 500 on heroku. heroku logs (shown below) says "relation 'microposts' does not exist" followed by some sql.  I'm not sure what to do, given that localhost runs fine.  Any ideas?

```
[sample_app (master)]$ heroku logs
==> production.log <==


Started GET "/" for 96.225.159.51 at Wed Nov 24 19:05:00 -0800 2010
  Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
Completed   in 18ms

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PGError: ERROR:  relation "microposts" does not exist
:             SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod), d.adsrc, a.attnotnull
              FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
                ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
             WHERE a.attrelid = '"microposts"'::regclass
               AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
             ORDER BY a.attnum
):
  app/controllers/pages_controller.rb:6:in `new'
  app/controllers/pages_controller.rb:6:in `home'


==> dyno-2890282.log <==
DEPRECATION WARNING: railtie_name is deprecated and has no effect. (called from require at /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:64)
>> Thin web server (v1.2.6 codename Crazy Delicious)
>> Maximum connections set to 1024
>> Listening on 0.0.0.0:51899, CTRL+C to stop
```

And here is the pages_controller.rb:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

  def home
    @title = "Home"
    if signed_in?
      @micropost = Micropost.new 
      @feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(:page => params[:page])
    end
  end

  def contact
    @title = "Contact"
  end

  def about
    @title = "About"
  end

  def help
    @title = "Help"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

OK...dumbest question ever.  I'm playing the newbie card....forgot the "heroku rake db:migrate".  All's well now.